# How to rewite CMSSignedDataGenerator to change SignedContentTypeOID?

Tags: bouncycastle

Recently,I used CMSSignedDataGenerator to sign message,I found that SignedContentTypeOID is 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1,I want to rewrite CMSSignedDataGenerator to change SignedContentTypeOID from 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 to 1.2.156.10197.6.1.4.2.2,coule someone can help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4fbU.png)

the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CMSTypedData` subclass passed to `CMSSignedDataGenerator.generate` should let you specify an explicit content type.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,there are 2 SEQUENCE's object id need to change,I changed 1 SEQUENCE's object ID which at the middle of PKCS7 struct according to your idea,there is another need to change at the beginning of PKCS7 struct.I looked at the source code of CMSSignedDataGenerator.generate,I found the following code:      ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(CMSObjectIdentifiers.signedData, sd); I found CMSObjectIdentifiers.signedData = "1.2.840.113549.1.7.2",so I think that I still need to rewrite CMSSignedDataGenerator。